# Is there any method in Java to init a set by step 1 or other length?

Tags: java

For example, I like to init a set like [1,2,3, ...,100].

Usually, we do as follows:

```
for(int i = 1;i <= 100;i++ ){
    set.add(i);
}
```

Is there any method to do this more conveniently?

Such as `someMethod(startIndex, endIndex, step);`

By using that, we can easily init a set like [1,2,3,4,5] or [1,3,5,7,9] or others.

Comment: your for-loop is just fine. if you need it a lot, wrap it in a method.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use Java 8 Streams.

For example :

```
Set<Integer> mySet = IntStream.range(1,101).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

or for odd numbers only :

```
Set<Integer> mySet = IntStream.range(1,101).filter(i->i%2==1).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

- `IntStream.range` is an easy way to obtains numbers in a given range.
- Then you can apply filters if you only want some of the numbers.
- Finally you can collect them to any collection you wish.

Comment: For odd numbers you could also do something like `IntStream.iterate(1, i -> i + 2).limit(51)...`.

Comment: @Keppil Yep, that would be more efficient

Comment: `IntStream.iterate(1, i -> i + 2).limit(51)` is not too readable. You have to calculate to understand it (instead of just reading `100`), and it is prone to off-by-one errors. Actually, this stream includes `101` as well.

Comment: @user140547: I think it is less error-prone, since you get exact control of the number of elements. It is probably just a matter of taste, so I just added that there is another way for those that prefer it.

Comment: There is also a `rangeClosed` method which allows you to use `100`as a parameter. 
example: `IntStream.rangeClosed(1,100)`

Comment: @Keppil If your problem is "get the first 51 odd elements", then that's fine. If your problem is "get the odd numbers from 1 to 100", then it's not.